# Removing duplicates in AWS Redshift using SQL

Tags: amazon-web-services, duplicates, amazon-redshift

**Summary:**
I've got a table which looks something like this

| Entity Id | Entity Name |
| --- | --- |
| 01 | Entity1 |
| 02 | Entity2 |
| 01 | Entity1 |
| 03 | Entity3 |

**Question**
I'm trying to remove duplicates using SQL proc but struggling to find a solution. Is there a way to remove duplicates in this case using just SQL? Ideally, I'd like to create a procedure which I can call when required to remove duplicates.

I tried using CTE and row_number() but struggling to get it working...

Answer (score 1):

If I glean your data correctly, a simple distinct select should work here:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT EntityId, EntityName
FROM yourTable;
```

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT would work if I was dumping data from this table to another. However, I want to remove duplicates from the existing table using SQL. Something similar to pandas df.drop_duplicates()

I've seen a solution where people create a new_table, dump distinct values from original table, drop original table and rename new_table to just table. However, I'm trying to avoid that approach.

Within existing table I want to remove duplicates..

Comment: Your new table approach with the above query is how I would probably go about this.  The problem is that your duplicate records are really identical in every way.  There is no proper primary key, so we can't easily use a regular delete statement.

Answer (score 0):

Your on the right track with row_number() but it looks like you are trying to delete all but one of the duplicated rows.  This isn't possible since there is no way to tell one copy from another.  You will need to do this in a few steps.

1. Save a single copy of duplicated rows into a temp table.  Using row_number() where this value equals 2 is a good way.
2. Delete all matching rows from the original table.
3. Insert the values from the temp table back into the original table.

You can do this in a transaction block so that no other user of the database will see the table with the rows missing.